# Coldfusion Query OF Query Generates more records than expected

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

This one has really stumped me

I have 3 queries

Query 1:

Complete query with series of where statements

Query 2 is query 1 ( minus all there where statements ) as I decide to create a query or queries instead

query 3 is the query of query where it references query 2 in the from statement and then has the where statements to filter the results received from query 2

I would expect the results from query 1 and 3 to be identical yet the query of queries outputs nearly 1500 records more than query 1

any advise suggestions why please enlighten me

```
<CFQUERY datasource="#Application.Workflow#" name="query1">
SELECT 
                * 
FROM
                Campaigns
INNER JOIN         
                CampaignReceipients
ON
                Campaigns.CampaignId=CampaignReceipients.CampaignId
WHERE
                Campaigns.CampaignId  = 191
AND
                ClientMobilePhone <> ''
AND
                ClientEmailAddress like '%@%'
AND
                ClientBusinessPhone is null 
AND
                ClientHomePhone is null 
AND 
                AssignedToDate is null
</CFQUERY>      
                
<CFQUERY datasource="#Application.Workflow#" name="query2">
SELECT 
                * 
FROM
                Campaigns
INNER JOIN         
                CampaignReceipients
ON
                Campaigns.CampaignId=CampaignReceipients.CampaignId
WHERE
                Campaigns.CampaignId  = 191
</CFQUERY>
                
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="query3">
SELECT 
                *
FROM
                query2
WHERE 
                ClientMobilePhone <> ''
AND
                ClientEmailAddress like '%@%'
AND
                ClientBusinessPhone is null 
AND
                ClientHomePhone is null 
AND 
                AssignedToDate is null
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data or your DB server type, I would still be confident of this being due to how CF query of queries handles `NULL` values in string comparisons.

With your original datasource level query, the comparison `WHERE ClientMobilePhone <> ''` will ignore all records `WHERE ClientMobilePhone IS NULL`.

Whereas with CF QoQ, `WHERE ClientMobilePhone <> ''` will return records where ClientMobilePhone is either NULL or not empty string.

SQL `ISNULL()` / `IFNULL()` is not supported here, but you can test for NULL separately; you can confirm if this is definitely what is happening, by adding a fourth query to the code in your question:

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="query4">
SELECT 
                *
FROM
                query2
WHERE 
                ClientMobilePhone <> '' AND ClientMobilePhone IS NOT NULL
AND
                ClientEmailAddress like '%@%'
AND
                ClientBusinessPhone is null 
AND
                ClientHomePhone is null 
AND 
                AssignedToDate is null
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Ok so i have tried your code and yes the number reduces from being over 1500 more than expected to only 200 more than expected so there is progress

each of the fields in the ms sql db are of type nvarchar(50)

Comment: so is there one standard approach i can use when testing for null and null so its consistent and works correctly for both normal queries and q of q

Comment: Difficult to explain that last 200 without seeing the data. Are these queries the exact SQL you are using or have you simplified or anonymised for posting here? Re the 'standard approach', the `ClientMobilePhone <>'' AND ClientMobilePhone IS NOT NULL` syntax would work in both MS SQL and CFQoQ SQL. Other concepts to be aware of include `ISNULL(ClientMobilePhone,'')<>''` in MS SQL, and the `null="true"` optional attribute of the `cfqueryparam` tag. But imo a 'standard approach' rarely makes sense, since QoQ syntax is a very limited subset of SQL, so we must code with that in mind when using it.

Comment: My guess is that if you applied that empty string logic to the ClientBusinessPhone and ClientHomePhone fields, the 200 extra records would go away.